# how to make many HTML elememt in js

Tags: javascript

I tried to make `<option>`s with the content in a select tag using a for loop

```js
var content = {
  0: "water"
  1: "tea"
  2: "coffee"
  3: "soda"
};
var selectTest = document.getElementById("test");
var createOpption = document.createElement("option");
var addOptionContent;

for (var i = 0; i < content.lenght; i++) {
  addOptionContent = document.createTextNode(content[i]);
  createOpption.appendChild(addOptionContent);
  selectTest.appendChild(createOpption);
}
```

```html
<select id="test"></select>
```

I expect that **each content will be in its own option tag** but the result is that **all content was in one option tag**

Comment: Typo in `content.lenght`. Also, your content variable is invalid. And for the length of an object, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: An object is not an array and has no length at all. Also you don't append to option , you want an option for each item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for in` loop to iterate object. You are treating `content` as an array which it isn't.

You also want a new element for each iteration

You can also use `new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected)` to create an `<option>`

```js
var content = {
  0: "water",
  1: "tea",
  2: "coffee",
  3: "soda"
};
var selectTest = document.getElementById("test");


for (var key in content){
  var createOpption = new Option( content[key], key);
  selectTest.appendChild(createOpption)
}
```

```html
<select id="test"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a Node for each not before

```
    let content = {
      0: "water",
      1: "tea",
      2: "coffee",
      3: "soda"
    };
    let selectTest = document.getElementById("test");


   for (let i in content) {
   let createOpption = document.createElement("option");
   createOpption.textContent=content[i];
   selectTest.appendChild(createOpption);
}
```

I also found this

```
selectTest.add(createOpption)
```

does the same thing might be better

Comment: I removed the textNode since its probably not necessary (at least not for this example)

Comment: did you mean the length ?

Comment: I meant try to run your code and see what you get. Fails for me. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vydw04sh/

Comment: An object literal has no length

Comment: there => fixed it

Comment: oh I forgot to copy that part

Comment: oO ? I hope I got everything nwo

Comment: Easiest way to know is click on `<>` in editor and make a runnable snippet